# Hyper link is not working for second row + Datatable

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have written the code to display records from Database using datatable lib.
after clicking on first time on any row that again fetches new records from DB.but after clicking the next any row it's not working. Pls suggest how to overcome from this problem. the code as follows.

```
            function Available() {

                var table = $('#example').DataTable();
                $('#example tbody').on( 'click', 'tr', function () {
                var obj2 = table.row( this ).data();


                var country = obj2.country;
                var collect_date = obj2.collect_date;
                var param = "?country="+obj2.country+"&collect_date="+obj2.collect_date;
                console.log(country+"" +collect_date);
            //  $("a").click(function() {           
                        $('#example2').DataTable( {
                        "sAjaxSource": '/available'+param,
                    //  "data": {"country": country, "collect_date": collect_date},
                        "columns": [
                            { "data":"country1" },
                            { "data":"country2" },
                            { "data":"country3" },
                            { "data":"country4"},
                            { "data":"country5"},
                            { "data":"country6"}
                                    ]


                                } );                    
            } );


                }
```

Comment: Hi Venkat thanks for your suggestion. but still am not able to get the record after clicking 2nd time.

Comment: share the fiddle url

Answer (score 0):

Try like below. you can access current TR by `$(this)`.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var table = $('#example').DataTable();

    $('#example tbody').on( 'click', 'tr', function () {
        if ( $(this).hasClass('selected') ) {
            $(this).removeClass('selected');
        }
        else {
            table.$('tr.selected').removeClass('selected');
            $(this).addClass('selected');
        }
    } );

} );
```